# Dropdown list with items removed based on second variable sorted by third variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm new to to C#/MVC. I have a list with four elements (NameID, Name, IsActive, and DisplayOrder). I wish to present a dropdown list to choose Name, but the list should include only those for which `IsActive = true`, and present the list in order based on `DisplayOrder`.

In View for Create I have

```
@Html.DropDownList("NameID");
```

and in Controller I have

```
public ActionResult Create()
    { 
        ViewBag.NameID = new SelectList(db.Names, "NameID", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

I would like to put the subsetting/display order info directly in the `ViewBag.NameID` line, using something like a `.Where(IsActive=true)` and `.OrderBy(DisplayOrder)` statement, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: are you familiar with linq.. ? here is a basic linq tutorial that yo ushould easily be able to implement based on your use case 
[Using Linq with where Clause](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_linq/article.php/c16829/Using-LINQ-with-Dynamic-Where-Clauses.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This belongs to the controller:

```
var names = db.Names.Where(n => n.IsActive).OrderBy(n => n.DisplayOrder);
var model = new SelectList(names, "NameID", "Name");

return this.View(model);
```

And in the corresponding view you should have code similar to this:

```
@model SelectList

@Html.DropDownList("someName", Model)
```

As the pattern you are using is called MVC, where M stands for Model, you should pass the data around between controller and a view using model and not the `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 1):

If you make yourself familiar with LINQ statements this is quite easy to achieve actually.

I have written a little sample code which clears everything up for you. (hopefully)

```
void Main()
{
    var members = new List<Member>();

    members.Add(new Member() {NameId = 1, Name = "Hank", IsActive = false, DisplayOrder = 3});
    members.Add(new Member() {NameId = 2, Name = "Walter", IsActive = true, DisplayOrder = 2});
    members.Add(new Member() {NameId = 3, Name = "Jimmy", IsActive = true, DisplayOrder = 1});
    members.Add(new Member() {NameId = 4, Name = "Bell", IsActive = false, DisplayOrder = 4});

    var myDropDownMembers = members.Where(m => m.IsActive == true).OrderBy(m => m.DisplayOrder);

    Console.WriteLine(myDropDownMembers);

}

class Member
{
    public Member() {}

    public int NameId;
    public string Name;
    public bool IsActive;
    public int DisplayOrder;
}
```

and the result is,

[image]

If you want to get familiar with LINQ have a look at these two tutorials and don't forget to have an sneak peak on MSDN helps on it also,

[LINQ Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/590978/LINQ-Tutorial-for-Beginners)

[Understanding LINQ (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19154/Understanding-LINQ-C)